# How can I use radiobuttonlist selectedvalue in autopostback event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

html File:

```
<p>Delivery Type :</p>
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
  <asp:ListItem Value="0">Electronic</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="1">Paper Mail</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Code-behind page:

```
protected void RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value = )
    {

    }
}
```

I want to use radiobutton so that if user selects the electronic mail option, the Email field should be displayed. So as per my knowledge I am trying if radiobuttonlist selected value is **0** then email field should be displayed. But I am getting an error in the `if` condition itself:

> cannot convert type string to bool

Comment: cannot convert type string to bool

Comment: `RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value` is string, so in _if_ you need compare it with string, like `RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value == "0"`

Answer (score 0):

When using several Radiobuttons (instead of Radio Button List) and manually setting them to the same group:

```
     <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="RadioButtonList" />
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="RadioButtonList" />
```

The following should work,

```
if(RadioButton1.Checked)
{

}
```

This way there should be no datatype conversions necessary, avoiding the errors you seem to be getting. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value == "0"){
}
```

Comment: == cannot be applied to operands of type string and int

Comment: @SachinR.Patel so simply try `RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Value == "0"`